# Do all API responses need to explicitly be returned with a json function?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-api

I'm getting into `api controllers` and am wondering if this `index function`:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = DB::table('galleries')->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

inside my `api controller` has to be returned with `response()->json()` or if it is OK to just return the variable:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = DB::table('galleries')->get();
    return $data;
}
```

Both seem to work. Are there reasons to use the former one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `return $data` will just convert the `$data` into a json response. no header will be set and your frontend will not recognize it as a json object.

`return response()` will return a full `Response` instance. from the doc

> Returning a full Response instance allows you to customize the response's HTTP status code and headers. A Response instance inherits from the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class, which provides a variety of methods for building HTTP responses

for `return response()->json()` method

> The `json` method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the `json_encode` PHP function

so this will be recognised as json object in your frontend. Read more at laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses).

Answer (score 1):

When you send something as a response which is not already an instance of a `Response` then Laravel will create a new instance of a `Response` with that as the content. When the response is sent and that object is an array (or arrayable) or something that is convertible to JSON then it is sent as a JSON response. At that point all relevant headers will be correct.

There are two parts of the source code to consider if you are curious on how this works:

1. [The part that checks whether the response is already an instance of `Response` and constructs one if not](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L812)
2. [The part that decides whether a response content should be JSON](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L83)

If you want my opinion then you should be doing `response()->json(...)` which creates a `JsonResponse` instance that has no chance to be ambiguous because otherwise you are relying on undocumented behavior which is subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Both seem , both are correct but if you send as json it will be formal and in the fornt-end site they can use easily